# Generating equation from python ARMA model summary

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I am new in python time-series analysis. My target is to use the libraries in python to learn the parameters. When I get the parameters I can built equitions and use the model to any other programming language. Keeping it in mind, I bult an ARMA model using the following code and got the following summary using the summary2 method of ARMA model.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, arma_order_select_ic

ts = pd.Series(df2.total_rating, index=df2.index, )
model = ARMA(ts, order=(5, 7)) #5,7 is decided using arma_order_select_ic method
results = model.fit(trend='nc', method='css-mle')
print(results.summary2())
```

[image]

My target is to get all the parameters shown in the following equation image of an ARMA model. As far I understand that for my case,$p$=5, $q$=7, $a_i$ =  coef for ar.$L_i$, $X_{t-i}$ = values from the time series data, $b_i$ = coef for ma.$L_i$, and $E_{t-i}$ = Std.Err from ma.$L_i$. But I am confused where to get the value of $c$ and $\epsilon$$_t$?

[image]

Please let me know if my above assumptions are correct and also how to get value of c and $\epsilon$$_t$ from the summary?

## Edit:

Consider the given time series data:

```
date    total_rating
13-01-2016  316964
14-01-2016  353527
15-01-2016  334453
16-01-2016  221652
17-01-2016  198445
19-01-2016  331156
20-01-2016  328149
21-01-2016  ?
```

If I run the following python code, the predicted value for 21-01-2016  is 343003.648569:

```
predictedDF = results.predict(start='01/01/2016', end='03/02/2017')
```

My question is how this predicted value is calculated from the equation and the results summary given above. It will be a great help if you kindly put the values in the equation and show me the calculation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's been updated since you asked the question, but for me doing `print(results.summary())` includes the constant, c, you described. My understanding is that epsilon is an error term so doesn't get assigned a value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you can specify the modeling library you are using to produce those results. That being said... $c$ is the constant you are going need to learn that parameter, or if you don't want a model with a constant just exclude it. Your $\epsilon$ term is the noise, in your results you'll see `S.D. of Innovations` this the standard deviation of the noise of your model so:

$$
\epsilon = \mathcal{N}(0, 25545.467^2)
$$

It appears you're using python so be careful if you're drawing random samples from np.random.normal or stats.normal.rvs as they are parameterized as $N(\mu, \sigma)$ not $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is good indication about $\epsilon$. However, I am a bit confused about the overall values. So, I have clarified the question by editing it. It will be a great help if you kindly answer accordingly.